# AVR ATmega328P wrong fuses set

Tags: atmega, reset, atmega328p, programmer, fuse-bits

I was programming on the AVR ATmega328P using the USBasp programmer. I uploaded the blink example but the LED was not blinking. Thus I went on changing the fuse bits to the one Arduino has. During this suddenly my avrdude crashed and my all fuse bits were set to zero. After that, I tried again and again but didn't work using the [external oscillator](http://www.larsen-b.com/Article/260.html) method. I used another chip to check if it isn't the issue of the programmer but it wasn't, as the new chip worked well. The oscillator method didn't work this time.

Now I want to erase the chip completely to reset. I currently have [this](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/EETools/CHIPMAX2?qs=vnwGVgFuQibaingLQoLWtQ%3D%3D) programmer available but I don't know how to use this for high voltage programming or if this supports that or not, as I couldn't find any clue in the software about that.

Comment: Surely the manual would tell which chips it can program and how? Basically a new Atmega328P costs about $3 in single units so is it worth spending much time how to revive it? Also, if the fuse bits all went to 0 like you say, it means the MCU can't be reprogrammed any more, if RSTDISBL is 0 so it won't respond to reset and LB lock bits being zero means further programming is disabled.

Comment: I can upload the code using this programmer but and change the fuses .But these are temporary in this and they are just considered when uploading the program, as I take it out the fuse bits are set back to my own. How can I permenently change them or if I can get a hex file kind of thing for the fuses as well

Comment: From what I could find, the only way that the ATmega328P can be hopelessly damaged (bricked) is from applied voltages beyond specification. But you might need to use high voltage parallel programming. I have a AVR Dragon with which I was able to revive a bricked device. Some links:  https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/bricked-atmega-328/  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/490943/can-an-atmega328p-be-bricked-such-that-it-cannot-be-programmed-but-still-works  https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-04E3421E-81C3-4E6C-BD29-9E1A7BAEBA7E-en-US-1/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution and after that my chip started to work fine, all the fuse bits were back to normal. The technique used was high-voltage parallel programming. I used the Arduino to send signals to the chip as shown in the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf). I first got the chip to programming mode. Then set fuse bits both high and low. Run my code in a loop it programmed and set fuses again and again. After that, I took a second Arduino and used that as an ISP. I went to avr dude and it worked fine. All fuse bits were back to normal. I guess it was due to the 11.7V reset voltage I used again and again(Inside loop). But this method worked for me.